# Cross-referencing alphabetically numbered list items

Tags: cross-referencing

The webpage
http://texblog.org/2012/03/21/cross-referencing-list-items/
teaches how to cross-reference items of a numbered list. But what if the list is alphabetically numbered? What can I do for cross-referencing items of such a list?

Comment: exavctly the same `\label` `\ref` commands work. What did you try?

Comment: It doesn't work well, because `\ref` prints the numbers corresponding to the referenced itens, not the correpondent letters (in the alphabetical order). I want to know how to print the letters instead the numbers.

Comment: `\begin{enumerate}\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\alph{enumi})}
  \item For all $A \subseteq X$, $f^{-1}[\overline{A}] \subseteq \overline{f^{-1}[A]}$;\label{TI:continuitybyclosures1}
  \item For all $B \subseteq Y$, $\overline{f^{-1}[B]} \subseteq f^{-1}[\overline{B}]$. \label{TI:continuitybyclosures2}
\end{enumerate}`

Comment: You have redefined the display label, which is the wrong thing to do really, you could redefine \theenumi instead then it would work, or use the `enumitem` paclage which gives an easier interface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have redefined the display label, which is the wrong thing to do really, you could redefine `\theenumi` instead then it would work, or use the `enumitem` package which gives an easier interface to all kinds of customisation of lists.